# how to highlight specific dates in angular date picker

Tags: angular, datepicker

I want to highlight those dates for which appointments are already booked. Dates can get from database in array form. I am using angular date picker.

I got many suggestions for similar problem for jQuery UI date picker, but didn't found for angular. Following is my angular datepicker-

```
            <div class="col-sm-4 date-picker-container">
                <div class="form-group form-float">
                    <div class="form-line"
                        ng-class="{ 'error': appointmentDetailsForm.appointmentDate.$touched && (appointmentDetailsForm.appointmentDate.$invalid ) }">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                            name="appointmentDate" ng-model="appointmentDetails.appointmentDate"
                            ng-pattern="/^(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\-](19|20)\d{2}$/"
                            ng-focus="showDatePicker = true" >
                        <date-picker ng-model="appointmentDetails.appointmentDate"
                            ng-show="showDatePicker" format-date="formatDate"
                            parse-date="parseDate"
                             id="appointmentDateId">
                        </date-picker>
                        <label class="form-label">Appointment Date</label>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: are you *sure* this is [tag:angular] and not [tag:angularjs]?

Comment: a `date-picker` directive isn't part of the core AngularJs library.  The ***specific 3rd party*** `date-picker` that you have chosen doesn't really support what you are trying to do.  You could either contact the maintainers about adding the feature, join the project and help them add the feature, or choose a different library, like ui-datepicker which has this functionality.

Comment: ohhk... @Claies thanks for guidence